# Обучаюсь языку Swift. Создаю приложение простые, никуда не выгружая, кроме гита! вылезла ошибка, о том что я превысил лимит приложений. Как убрать?

Tags: swift

Ошибка вылезла:
1)Communication with Apple failed.
Your maximum App ID limit has been reached. You may create up to 10 App IDs every 7 days.

2)No profiles for 'AM.ColorView' were found
Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'AM.ColorView'.

Убрал аккаунт на None, вылезла другая:
Signing for "ColorView" requires a development team.
Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor.

Answer (score 0):

В учебных целях, вам нужно в свойствах проекта указывать один и тот же Bundle Identifier для разных проектов (вида com.example.app). Иначе действительно выходит, что вы пытаетесь создать много приложений на бесплатном аккаунте.